# Проблема с установкой Node js на Ubuntu. В чем причина?

Tags: ubuntu

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'node-jsv' for regex 'node.js'
Note, selecting 'node-jsdom' for regex 'node.js'
Note, selecting 'node-jsesc' for regex 'node.js'
Note, selecting 'node-json-stringify-safe' for regex 'node.js'
Note, selecting 'node-jscoverage' for regex 'node.js'
Note, selecting 'node-jssip' for regex 'node.js'
Note, selecting 'node-jsonparse' for regex 'node.js'
node-jsdom is already the newest version (0.8.10+dfsg1-1).
node-jsesc is already the newest version (0.5.0-1).
node-json-stringify-safe is already the newest version (5.0.0-1).
node-jsonparse is already the newest version (1.0.0-1).
node-jssip is already the newest version (0.6.34-5).
node-jsv is already the newest version (4.0.0+ds1-1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer           required:
libllvm3.8 libqmi-glib1 ubuntu-core-launcher
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/249 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
dpkg: error processing package hunspell-en-gb (--configure):
package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
hunspell-en-gb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: По моему, проблема с hunspell en-gb...  Что это такое, что с ней случилось и как исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема описана в приведённом вами выводе:

> dpkg: error processing package hunspell-en-gb (--configure):
>   package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
>   reinstall it before attempting configuration

Пакет с именем **hunspell-en-gb** находится в повреждённом состоянии, поэтому его надо **переустановить**. Один из способов переустановки пакета:

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq hunspell-en-gb
sudo apt install hunspell-en-gb
```

После чего можно снова попробовать запустить установку ноды (возможно потребуется предварительная перезагрузка).

Comment: Все отлично получилось, спасибо друг, помог.  Долго искал, натыкался лишь на корявые советы, которые не работали...